# React-Native-Firebase: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using [react-native-firebase/auth](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#emailpassword-sign-in). While the code correctly logs in when online, I keep getting the following **network error** if offline:

```
A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred
```

How can I catch that?

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'

auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    console.log(user)
})

auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
})
```

I've found other similar questions, but no one seems to solve this problem.